# What can be done with a corrupt h2 database? (when recover tool doesn't help)

Tags: h2

I have a h2 database powering a java webapp, today the application stopped responding.  Despite no real glitches for over a year, the app stopped and was throwing JDBC `PoolExhaustedException` exceptions claiming the pool was empty.

Eventually I had to kill the process as it wouldn't shut down cleanly.

Unfortunately after this point the app would not start, h2 was now throwing an `MetaDataAccessException : org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException"`

So it seemed the database had become corrupt, so I decided to give the Recover tool a try.

This also failed to complete, after 20 minutes of it processing, it would fail with an `IllegalStateException: Unsupported type 17 [1.4.190/3]`

At this point I had no other course of action except to restore the previous nights backup.  Not the optimal result but I could not find any other recommended action.

So I want to ask here was there any other option available to me?  I'm very concerned at the reliability of h2, can it be depended on? If it's own recover tools aren't reliable then are there other 3rd party database recovery tools which do a better job?

It made me wonder also about relying on the single file to encompass all tables approach,  like in this case - once something goes wrong...everything goes wrong.

Therefore is it better to use the system h2 has (at least I think) where it creates a different db file for each table?

Comment: Something very strange happening today..  another customer with the same PoolExhausted issue.  Their system hasn't been modified for months so I'm very surprised to see two in one day, luckily restarting their server resolved the issue.. but for how long is a worry.